# How to append data after JSON compare in CSV?

Tags: python, json, csv

I would like to write a script that after sorting a CSV compares it with a JSON file and adds a character if there is a match.
I wrote the beginning of the script I manage to compare my CSV with the JSON.

What I can't do is add a character in my CSV when I find the same info in the JSON.

My last test is the following:

```
with open('C:\\Users\\jimmy\\Desktop\\test\\service.json', 'r') as servicefile:
    data_service = json.load(servicefile)
    # print(data_service)
    for row in reads:
        for rows in data_service:
            if row["Nom"] in rows["displayName"]:
                servicetype.append(row["Nom"] + 'test')
                with open('C:\\Users\\jimmy\\Desktop\\test\\eggs.csv', 'a', newline='') \
                        as csvfile:
                    fieldnames = ['Nom', 'Ligne Responsable du Sujet', 'NÂ° de CI',
                                  'Commentaire', 'Responsable' ]
                    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, delimiter=';', fieldnames=fieldnames)
                    print(servicetype)
                    writer.writerow(row)
            else:
                print('no')
```

Can't find a solution to add a character in my name cell when I have the same information in my JSON.

EDIT

Add var like

```
extra_chars= 'test'
```

And add before writer.writerow(row)

```
row["Nom"] = row["Nom"] + extra_chars
```

Comment: maybe first compare and add char in data in memory, and later write all data to csv.

Comment: do you get error message when you run in console? always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: you have to read full csv to memory, next make modification in memory and later write all data again to file - you can't add some value in row - you have to write all rows again. And don't write to CSV when you read from this  CSV

Comment: thanks for the answer i don't understand when you say make modification in memory ? how i can do this? @furas

Comment: I meas - read all data from file to list (and `list` is in RAM memory in computer), modify data in this list, and later write all data back to file. So don't do every modification on file but on list

Comment: You can add characters to the name by doing a `row["Nom"] = row["Nom"] + extra_chars` *before* calling `writer.writerow(row)`.